# RemoveOutputCacheItem in Html.RenderAction dontWork in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

i have a actionResult when i cache this action ,this item cached

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
public ActionResult LoadMenu()
    {
        var dbContext = new DataContext();
        var menus = dbContext.menues.Include(x => x.Page).Where(x => x.Type == (int)EnumCodes.menuType.isHeader && x.Status == (int)EnumCodes.menuStatus.active).OrderBy(x => x.priority).ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
        return View(menus);
    }
```

when i use RemoveOutputCacheItem for this action

```
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action("LoadMenu", "Menu"));
```

and look this action in view the cache removed.
but when use this action by Html.RenderAction in other view cach is Remains.
why cache is Remains?

Comment: But if the action is rendered from another view, the URL for output cache is different, so nothing cached?

Comment: does not matter, this action is cached